\"code\":\"UnsupportedRequestContent\",\"message\":\"Request content is not well formed or supported.\"}
I am new to Ansible and I am trying to create Azure diagonistics settings for Azure VNET using ansible module azure_rm_resource. And I am getting this specific error. I am not sure how to fix it. Any suggetsion would help here.
Ansible task:

- name: Create Log diagonistics Setting with storage account
         azure_rm_resource:
                url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet1/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/test?api-version=2021-05-01-preview
                method: PUT
                client_id: "{{ client_id }}"
                secret: "{{ secret_val }}"
                tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
                subscription_id: "{{ subscription }}"
                body:
                   properties:
                          storageAccountId: /subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/staccount 
                          metrics:
                              category: AllMetrics
                              enabled: true
                          logs:
                              categoryGroup: allLogs
                              enabled: true
                          logAnalyticsDestinationType: null

I have tried this with Log analyics workspace workspaceId still the same issue. changed the api version but it didnt work. Tried with the ansible module azure.azcollection.azure_rm_monitordiagnosticsetting but it was not recognised although I had azure.azcollection installed.
I want to create/update diagonostic settings for azure resources

- name: Create Log diagonistics Setting with storage account
         azure_rm_resource:
                url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet1/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/test?api-version=2021-05-01-preview

Url should be escased in quotes and sub_id substituted as follows:
url: "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{ subscription }}/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet1/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/test?api-version=2021-05-01-preview"

Also substitute other fields if their values are stored in variables.
body:
    properties:
        storageAccountId: /subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/staccount 
        metrics:
          category: AllMetrics
          enabled: true
        logs:
          categoryGroup: allLogs
          enabled: true
        logAnalyticsDestinationType: null

You need to encase the storage account ID in quotes and substitute again as required.
In the logs section, I don't believe categoryGroup can be used - Not for a virtual network (Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks). Use category - the same as in metrics, and the only supported category at this time is VMProtectionAlerts.
Another thing to mention is that category groups were only introduced in November 2021, and the API version your using is May 2021 preview, so you'll need to use a newer management API version if you ever need to specify category groups in the future.
So, your yaml should look like this:
Ansible task:

- name: Create Log diagonistics Setting with storage account
         azure_rm_resource:
                url: "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{ subscription }}/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet1/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/test?api-version=2021-05-01-preview"
                method: PUT
                client_id: "{{ client_id }}"
                secret: "{{ secret_val }}"
                tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
                subscription_id: "{{ subscription }}"
                body:
                   properties:
                          storageAccountId: "/subscriptions/{{ subscription }}/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/staccount 
                          metrics:
                              category: AllMetrics
                              enabled: true
                          logs:
                              category: VMProtectionAlerts
                              enabled: true
                          logAnalyticsDestinationType: null

